# Facebook Messenger in the browser keeps logging me out

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, facebook-messenger

Using a Lenovo Chromebook C330 2-in-1 Convertible Laptop and want to use Messenger. Thing is, don't want to have it installed natively to not deal with notifications. Therefore, currently using the web app version.

In the Messenger web app version upon login I checked the "Keep me signed in" button yet anytime I go to back to it again it logs out and shows the cookie notice again and again.

How to stay logged in?

Comment: Do you have some "Internet security" suite or "cleaner" applications that might be clearing the cookies for you?

Comment: also, your laptop model is pretty much irrelevant; relevant would be your browser and a list of all plugins that are active on facebook's websites. Quite likely, and not unreasonably, something is deleting facebook cookies - to keep your privacy intact (facebook is a billions-dollar company *exclusively* by selling everyone's private data, and they do get to track you on every website that embeds some facebook or facebook partner element, i.e. nearly every major website); but if you *want* to use facebook messenger, then you need to be cleverer than that.

Comment: Using Google Chrome @MarcusMüller

Comment: @Mokubai not that Im aware of

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres list of all browser plugins active on facebook's website?